# Azure Gateway VPN IP different from actual Public IP

Tags: azure, networking

I have a Virtual Network Gateway setup on my Azure subscription, and a number of VMs which connect to it.

The VN Gateway created a Public IP automatically, and has it listed in the 'Overview' screen.
However going onto any website to check my IP (e.g. whatsmyip.org) gives me an entirely different Public IP. Anyone know why this is?

My configuration of the Virtual Network Gateway is very basic with mostly defaults and the VpnGw1 SKU.

Comment: You are trying to check IP address from Azure VM, do they have Public IP assigned?

Comment: Yes - a Public IP is assigned to the Virtual Network Gateway. After logging into the VPN using Tunnelblick, and then logging into a VM, the Public IP shown while inside the VM is different to that of the Virtual Network Gateway that's shown on the Azure portal

Comment: Check if it is not an IP address of VM it-self

Comment: If you want to send traffic over NSA of etv., you should create routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public IP assigned to the virtual network gateway is a public IP to let you connect Azure VPN gateway from your on-premises network or the Internet.

However, by default, there is a default route to make that Azure VM can continue to accept and respond to requests from the Internet directly. If VM has been assigned a public IP address to the NIC, the outbound traffic from VM will use this IP address. If the VM does not have a public IP address, Azure translates the private source IP address of the outbound flow to a public source IP address. This public IP address is not configurable, cannot be reserved, and does not count against the subscription's public IP resource limit. Read [Outbound connections scenario overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#scenarios).

So the outbound public IP of Azure VM is different than the virtual network gateway public IP.

Comment: Hi - sorry for not getting back to you sooner, and thanks for the answer.
I don't quite have my answer yet, but this does definitely help - 
So none of my VMs have a public IP assigned to them using Azure; from my understanding the public Internet can only see the public IP of the gateway from which the VMs are connected through. 
But you're saying each VM will have a different Public IP from the Gateway despite coming through the Gateway?
I've visited the link you posted, but I still don't understand

Comment: In fact, even without public IP assigned to Azure VM, Azure VM still can connect to the Internet because there is a [default route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview#default) to the Internet. Only with VPN gateway, you have inbound IP from Azure VPN gateway but the outbound still can connect to the Internet unless you add a high priority route back to the VPN gateway or your on-premise network.

Comment: Thanks for this - I actually found that there was a NAT gateway which traffic was going through, so that was the issue!

Comment: Yes, [NAT gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-overview) is a new concept in recent years for me. I have marked your comment as useful, you may accept this answer for other members' to get more reference here.